# how to fix this geometry in three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am trying to translate geometry canvas2d commands which are generated at a separate library to three.js webgl output.
I have cutted one example and have a canvas2d output in one fiddle and the corresponding three.js fiddle.
As you can see the three.js output is not correct.
So I have to modify the library which generates the commands or add/remove commands or change three.js parameters itself.
Please can someone help me to fix the example?

Here is the canvas2d fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/onifs/a1L87mhb/2/

`var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");`

And here the three.js one:
https://jsfiddle.net/onifs/s6xn0obu/13/

`constructPathShape = new THREE.Shape();`

Please click "more" button several times to see how the shape is constructed.

TIA

Comment: welcome to stack overflow. You're required to put the code the question itself. Just linking to a fiddle is off topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have updated the fiddle. Now I don't need to create holes! I use ShapePath(true) instead.

https://jsfiddle.net/onifs/s6xn0obu/31/
(scroll down a little bit)

```
var simpleShapes = constructPathShape.toShapes( true );
    for ( var j = 0; j < simpleShapes.length; j ++ ) {
        var simpleShape = simpleShapes[ j ];
        var shape3d = new THREE.ExtrudeBufferGeometry( simpleShape, {
                depth: 2,
                bevelEnabled: false
        } );
        var material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({
            color: 0xff8800
        });

        var mesh = new THREE.Mesh( shape3d, material );
        scene.add( mesh );
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Once main contour is complete, you need to populate [Shape.holes](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/extras/core/Shape.holes)

Fixed fork of your fiddle can be found here: https://jsfiddle.net/mmalex/6khnx2zy/

```js
...
command[i++] = "constructPathShape.closePath();"; //outer contour is complete

command[i++] = "{ let hole = new THREE.Shape(); "
             + "  hole.autoClose = false; " 
             + "  constructPathShape.holes.push(hole); "
             + "  constructPathShape.holes[0].moveTo( -39.196, -59.186); "
             + "}";

// !!! IMPORTANT: starting from now address .holes[0]
command[i++] = "constructPathShape.holes[0].bezierCurveTo( -38.412,-47.08,-34.342,-37.412,-26.98,-30.181);";
command[i++] = "constructPathShape.holes[0].bezierCurveTo( -19.62,-22.952,-10.54,-19.337,0.261,-19.337);";
command[i++] = "constructPathShape.holes[0].bezierCurveTo( 12.194,-19.337,21.905,-23.867,29.397,-32.925);";
command[i++] = "constructPathShape.holes[0].bezierCurveTo( 34.274,-38.761,37.236,-47.515,38.282,-59.186);";
command[i++] = "constructPathShape.holes[0].lineTo( -39.196, -59.186);";

command[i++] = "constructPathShape.holes[0].closePath();";

command[i++] = " \/* we're done *\/ ;";
```

[image: dynamically construct three.js shape with holes]

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/276572/should-one-advise-on-off-topic-questions

Comment: Partially agree, in this case the person did not manage to ask properly, though the problem is totally valid and worth attention. Additionally the solution will be useful to community, as this is very typical when three.js developers do not understand how shape with holes work.

Comment: It's not useful if the question is not useful so either fix the question or vote to close and ask the asker to fix the question

Comment: @gman. Should I post the whole constructpath code? I think this is not useful!

Comment: I think the hole has a different clockwise direction than the outer shape path. Isn't Three able to detect this? Do I have to use another triangulation library to detect holes?

Comment: the direction is important, but seems that in your case the rule fits three.js and data points result in valid shape